# Why are my NSWorkspace notification and listeners not being recieved or firing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swiftui

I recieve no errors, my app runs with no errors. None of the events are triggered at sleep / wake or when the listened are registered.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct NotificationsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {
        
        func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
            NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("sleepListener")), name: NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification, object: nil)
            NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("wakeUpListener")), name: NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification, object: nil)
        }

        @objc private func sleepListener(_ aNotification: Notification) {
            print("listening to sleep")
            
            if aNotification.name == NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification {
                print("Going to sleep")
            } else if aNotification.name == NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification {
                print("Woke up")
            } else {
                print("Some other event other than the first two")
            }
        }
    }
}

func sleepListener() {
 print("Sleep Listening");
}

func wakeUpListener() {
 print("Wake Up Listening");
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you add `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate` too your `App` struct?

Comment: @jnpdx no, but when I add a `@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor` I start to get errors like: `-[_TtCV13Notifications16NotificationsApp11AppDelegate sleepListener]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003670290`

Comment: Ah -- sorry about the `NS` vs `UI` mixup. I suggest you use a more modern Combine or async/await approach and avoid the old `objc` code and `Selector`s -- then, the compiler can help you out of those issues

Comment: Better yet, since you're using SwiftUI, you _could_ just use `onReceive` on your `View`...

Comment: @jnpdx That is actually what I was trying to do originally with something like `.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification), perform: { _ in` but I had the same issue with nothing being triggered.

Comment: It isn't `NotificationCenter.default` it's `NSWorkspace.shared`

Comment: When I try that I get: `Type 'NotificationCenter' has no member 'shared'`

Comment: No, not `NotificationCenter.shared` -- `NSWorksapce.shared`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256799/discussion-between-ian-and-jnpdx).